# Pattern matching refuses to recognize member type (value X is not a member of _2)

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

In the following situation Scala seems to not acknowledge the type of `system`:

```
sealed trait Bar[S] {
  def system: S
}

trait Foo { def bar(): Unit }

trait FooBar extends Bar[Foo]
```

If I'm not completely confused, this means that I should be able to do the following:

```
def test(fb: FooBar) { fb.system.bar() }  // ok, this works
```

But the following fails:

```
trait Test[S] {
  val bar: Bar[S]

  bar match {
    case fb: FooBar => fb.system.bar() // error: value bar is not a member of _2
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

Is this a bug in the pattern matcher, or am I missing a crucial bit?

---

**EDIT**: Note, the following works:

```
trait Test[S] {
  val bar: Bar[S]

  bar match {
    case fb: FooBar => (fb: FooBar).system.bar()
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

I guess I should file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure is definitely involved here, but I'm not 100% sure that what you are seeing is a bug or expected behavior.  Because you declare the `bar` val as `Bar[S]`, `S` gets erased and the pattern matcher does not have the underlying type to work with.  You can see the erasure warning by changing your match to:

```
case fb:Bar[Foo] =>
```

The odd thing is that if you declared `bar` as type `Any` your original match would work.  Also, if you hover over `fb` in your match statement, you can see that it's being treated as:

```
Bar[S] with FooBar
```

Again, I believe this all goes back to how `bar` is being declared.  Not sure this is a bug though and I imagine someone with more experience in the inner workings of the pattern matcher might have a more in depth explanation.

Comment: `FooBar` is a flat type, so there is no problem with erasure. Also note that the compiler accepts my type annotation `(fb: FooBar)`, so there is definitely something odd with the type emitted by the match case.